# NetBeans Platform: Setting dependencies/accessing methods from other modules

Tags: java, netbeans, dependencies, netbeans-platform

I have a question regarding the use of NetBeans Platform and setting dependencies or simply referencing classes from another module.

What I have:

NetBeans Platform Application with a main module called Viewer

```
com.demo.viewer
 -MainScreenTopComponent.java
```

And I have a module named MenuToolbar

```
com.demo.toolbar
 -menutoolbar.java
 -action1.java
```

menutoolbar.java has a method that I would like to access from the MainScreenTopComponent.

I have tried right clicking the Viewer module, going to properties >Libraries and adding dependency on the MenuToolbar module, however I still cannot even import the package.

Any help is appreciated =(

Thank You!

**Edit:** Solved myself. Instead of adding dependency in Viewer, I added a Warpped Jar which I found in my platform's Build/Clusters/Modules folder!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use a wrapped JAR.

You need to export the classes from within the module MenuToolbar:

1. right click on your module
2. select properties
3. click on "API Versioning"
4. check the package `com.demo.toolbar` in the list of packages labelled "Public Packages"

This assumes your MenuToolbar module is already part of your NetBeans platform application

Comment: Thank You NetBeans God! It worked and oh glory, it worked well!